# Why can't I play as my model properly?

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

I give up. It's not wotking.
I can't move properly, I can't jump, my animation doesn't play and the output says

> "humanoid is not a valid member of Model "Workspace.olimolimolim443"".

This is the code I copied from the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2MFFBvIF6Y&list=LL&index=5). I did everything right so I don't know why it's not working, I spent like 5 hours trying to make this ugly creature move and I'm pissed off.

```
local char = script.Parent
local humanoid = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

local walkAnim = script:WaitForChild("walk")
local walkAnimTrack = char.humanoid.Animator:LoadAnimaton(walkAnim)

humanoid.Running:Connect(function(speed)
    if speed < 0 then
        if not walkAnimTrack.IsPlaying then
            walkAnimTrack:Play()
        end
    else
        if walkAnimTrack.IsPlaying then
            walkAnimTrack:Stop()
        end
    end
end)
```